# JS for render partials, how not to reload the page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a main page with 3 tabs, details, interns and analyst_system.

In interns tab I have a table, the same for the analyst_system table.

I want sortable columns the both table, so I used the gem "meta_search". Works fine, but my problem is when I clicked in column name, the page reload and go to the details tab.

So, I need use JS, it's correct?
I'm looking for tutoriais, but my code is different, I'm using render partials.

```
--controller
----welcome_controller.rb
----hr_curriculum_interns_controller.rb
...
views
--welcome
----index.html.erb
--hr_curriculum_interns 
----_table_hr_curriculum_interns.html.erb
```

app/controller/welcome_controller.rb

```
def index
  @keyword = params[:keyword]
  @category = params[:category]

  @search = HrCurriculumIntern.search(params[:search])
  @hr_curriculum_interns = @search.all
end
```

views/welcome/index

```
  <div class="container">
  <ul class="tabs" data-tabs data-toggle="tab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#main"><%= t('labels.main') %></a></li>
    <li><a href="#interns"><%= t('labels.interns') %></a></li>
    <li><a href="#analysts"><%= t('labels.analysts') %></a></li>
  </ul>  

<div class="tab-content">

<div id="main" class="active">
  <%= render "search" %>
</div>

<div id="interns" >
  <%#= render "hr_curriculum_interns/hr_curriculum_interns_filter" %>
  <%= render "hr_curriculum_interns/table_hr_curriculum_interns" %>
</div>

<div id="analysts" >
  <%= render "hr_curriculum_systems_analysts/table_hr_curriculum_systems_analysts" %>
</div>
```

app/views/hr_curriculum_interns/_table_hr_curriculum_interns

```
<table class="zebra-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :date_interview, t('attributes.date_interview') %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :name, t('attributes.name') %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :college, t('columns.college') %></th>
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :major, t('columns.major') %></th>      
    <th><%= sort_link @search, :answer_sent, t('columns.answer_sent') %></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <%# @hr_curriculum_interns = HrCurriculumIntern.all %>
  <% @hr_curriculum_interns.each do |hr_curriculum_intern| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= display_date(hr_curriculum_intern.date_interview) %></td>
      <td><%= smart_truncate(hr_curriculum_intern.name) %></td>     
      <td><%= smart_truncate(hr_curriculum_intern.college) %></td>
      <td><%= smart_truncate(hr_curriculum_intern.major) %></td>
      <td><%= hr_curriculum_intern.answer_sent %></td>
      <td><%= show_icon hr_curriculum_intern, hr_curriculum_intern, "data-default-action" => true %></td>
      <td> <%= edit_icon hr_curriculum_intern, edit_hr_curriculum_intern_path(hr_curriculum_intern) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to image_tag('icons/destroy.png'), hr_curriculum_intern, method: :delete, data: { confirm: t('messages.are_you_sure') } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

How can I do for the page not reload when I sortable any column?

Sorry for my english :PP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to go for gem 'data_table' instead of gem "meta_search" !
This will cover your all required, such as :

```
 pagination
 sorting
 searching
```

As internally above functionalities are managed by Javascript hence; on sorting/searching  it updates only the table sections rather than loading the complete Page.

Follow this : 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

Comment: Thanks, I will to use that =]